# Add the element if it doesn't already exist in java

Tags: java

I have created this method that is supposed to add a phone number to the ArrayList only if it is not already there.

```
private ArrayList<AlbanianPhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
public void addPhoneNumber (AlbanianPhoneNumber newPhoneNumber) {
    
    if(phoneNumbers.contains(newPhoneNumber)) {
        //number already exists
    }
    else {
         phoneNumbers.add(newPhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

At the main method, I added 2 same phone numbers, and they both were printed in the console, which is not supposed to happen, because only one of them should be printed. How can i fix it?

```
    person.addPhoneNumber(new AlbanianPhoneNumber(69,6956416));
    person.addPhoneNumber(new AlbanianPhoneNumber(69,6956416));
    System.out.println(person.getPhoneNumbers().toString());
```

//NOTE: AlbanianPhoneNumber class constructs a phone number using 2 fields, the first one represents the operator number and the second one the subscriber number.

Comment: A Collections that does not allow duplicates is btw. called a `Set` in java and there are already a couple of implementations like `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet` that you could use. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes. If you're going to have an ArrayList without duplicates, why not just use @OHGODSPIDERS 's suggestion and use a `Set`?

Answer (score 1):

You should override the equals and hashCode methods of your class AlbanianPhoneNumber.

If you see the source code of the contains method of ArrayList class, it based on the equals method, and the default equals method check the reference object not the value.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the default equals() implementation in `AlbanianPhoneNumber`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    AlbanianPhoneNumber that = (AlbanianPhoneNumber) o;
    return operator == that.operator && subscriberNumber == that.subscriberNumber;
}
```

Additionally if you use a `Set` (like `HashSet`) you wouldn't need to check if the element exists in the collection.